# Fill div with url parameter, but only if another span is empty after using settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two different ways that a person's name will be displayed on a page. Either in url, or if they filled out a form with their email the CMS I use will display their name. The two methods kind of conflict with eachother.

So basically I have a function that takes the person's name after "first_name" in url. That works great. But before it does that I want it to check if another div is empty but only after a delay of a couple seconds so that if the CMS is going to fill that  it has time to.

so I want it to wait a few seconds, check the span to see if it's empty and then if it's empty fill the div with the name from the url.

This what I have right now

HTML

```
<div id="firstName"></div> <!--Fill this one if the other one is empty -->
<span merge-tag="{{lead.first_name}}"></span> <!--Check to see if this one is empty before filling div -->
```

Javascript

```
// URL Parser
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return 'blank';
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

//First Name from URL
var firstName = getParameterByName('first_name');

//Function to add first name to div if span with merge-tag="{{lead.first_name}}" is empty. 
function addName() {
    if ($("[merge-tag={{lead.first_name}}]").is(':empty')) {
        document.getElementById("firstName").innerHTML = firstName.toString();
    }
}

window.settimeout(addName, 5000);
```

It's not working and I'm wondering if anyone has any idea as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be just a typo in the question, but the settimeout method should be setTimeout (capital T).

Also, try adding single quotes around {{lead.first_name}} in the handler:

```
if ($("[merge-tag='{{lead.first_name}}']").is(':empty')) {
  document.getElementById("firstName").innerHTML = firstName.toString();
}
```

Comment: Does that make a difference? I'll test it just a min.

Comment: I noticed another typo - I've update the answer. I think you'd need to change both things for it to work.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! The example I was looking at for attribute=value, didn't have quotes around it, so I didn't add it. But I thought that was odd. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_equal_value.asp